# Dataframe create multiple rows based on result set

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column with the value of 3898000.  I need to create another dataframe that will have 10 rows in which I subtract 1000 de-incrementally from my value in the first dataframe.  so the final second dataframe would have

```
3888000
3889000
3890000
3891000
3892000
3893000
3894000
3895000
3896000
3897000
```

I'm new at R...so that's why I'm struggling with this.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear: *"I subtract 1000 de-incrementally "* What does that mean? In your expected output values are *increasing* by 1000. Also: *"I have a dataframe that has a column with the value of 3898000"*  So your column has only one single entry? In other words, your `data.frame` has only one row? Is that really what you mean?

Comment: Or maybe there are many rows but all have the 3898000 value? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have extracted the target number from the first table. Here we create a new table with one column, filled with a sequence where each next line is 1000 less than the prior line. (Note, the OP shows an ascending sequence, which would use 1000 instead of -1000 below.)

```
result_extracted_from_table <- 3898000

new_table <- data.frame(
  my_column = seq(from = result_extracted_from_table, 
  by = -1000, length.out = 10)
)
```

Output:

```
new_table
   my_column
1    3898000
2    3897000
3    3896000
4    3895000
5    3894000
6    3893000
7    3892000
8    3891000
9    3890000
10   3889000
```

Comment: thanks a bunch.  sorry for the confusion on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq()` to create a sequence starting at 1,000 and increments by 1,000 for each row in the `dplyr::data_frame()`. `dplyr::mutate()` is used to subtract the sequence from the initial column and put the result into a new column:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(v1 = rep(3898000, 10)) %>%
  mutate(v2 = v1 - seq(1000, 1000*nrow(.), 1000))

#        v1      v2
#     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 3898000 3897000
# 2 3898000 3896000
# 3 3898000 3895000
# 4 3898000 3894000
# 5 3898000 3893000
# 6 3898000 3892000
# 7 3898000 3891000
# 8 3898000 3890000
# 9 3898000 3889000
# 10 3898000 3888000
```

`dplyr::select()` is can then be used to create a data_frame with only the new values.